# AccessViolationException when hosting FireBirdSql in a WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, firebird, access-violation, integer-overflow

I'm hosting the WCF service as a managed Windows service, and I keep getting an AccessViolationException when the consumer/client invokes its method for a second, third or fourth time. The crashes are completely random, so sometimes it might not crash until several more invocations later.

Here's the code with syntax highlighting for easier reading: http://pastebin.com/Z3Z06944

See the comments around the private method "CheckUser", since that's where the exception might be occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the code you posted, and I don't see what this has got to do with WCF. You say that commenting out the code for invoking the FireBirdSql (FbCommand?) and the AV goes away. Clearly the problem is with FireBirdSql. Try updating to the latest version, or send the crash report to the developers. An AV (access violation) typically occurs with a problem in the p/invoke unmanaged code interop layer. It sounds like some kind of multithreading problem which would be brought out in a WCF scenario.

(update: edited OP question title to include FbSQL reference)

Comment: The AddUser() method also contains an FbCommand object which I didn't comment out. When I comment out the two lines inside CheckUser() and return a dummy value, there are no more crashes. Also, I'm already using the latest version of Firebird's embedded SQL database.

Comment: @dc200 so when you comment out some FBsql code in checkuser, it stops crashing. I still don't get your point. It's FBSql. I would put money on it.

Comment: @dec200 you accepted my answer - care to update the question so that other FB users can benefit from the same fix?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are not explicitly closing the connection.

Since you are using the using statement it will get closed but there may be a delay.

If there is a max number of connections and the requests are coming quickly, you could get an exception if the max number is reached.

This would explain the random nature of the errors.

**Edit**

Your code is vulnerable to an sql server injection attack, you should fix that.

Your problem could be a locking error, do you have an index on user and password, if not you are doing a table scan, which locks the table.

Comment: Closing the connections was the first thing I tried. The problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that there are better Role / Membership provider systems in place but based on your code, you could improve this with TRY/FINALLY contructs, with the using statement.

```
    public Boolean AddUser(string user, string pass)
    {
        using (FbConnection con = new FbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBi"].ConnectionString.ToString()))
        {
            using (FbCommand fbComm = new FbCommand("INSERT INTO users (name, pass) VALUES ('" + user + "','" + pass + "')", con))
            {
                fbComm.Connection.Open();
                if (CheckUser(user, pass, con) == 0)                        
                {
                    fbComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    return true;
                }
                fbComm.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Have a great day!